# Show the name of the other table by pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The tables:

**users**

-id

-name

**users_companies**

-id

-user_id

-company_id

**companies**

-id

-name

*users_companies is the pivot table*

I want to show or get the "name" field of a table, this is my code in the table

```
<td>{{ $user->company }}</td>
```

but then it shows like this in the column of the table. I just want to get the value of the name like "VCY BT Holdings". Thanks

`[{"id":5,"name":"VCY BT Holdings","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2017-12-23 02:24:50","updated_at":"2017-12-23 02:24:50","pivot":{"user_id":14,"company_id":5}}]`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhTFq.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solved, but make sure you have define many-to-many relationship in `User.php` model

```
class User extends Model {

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Company')
    }
}
```

Then use loop to get each company

```
@foreach ($user->company as $company)
<li>{{ $company->name }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: It shows an error "Trying to get property of non-object"